# keypad not working for UITextField in UIActionSheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

The actionsheet appears with textfield.when i clicked on textfield,the keypad appears but not working means..when i was typed they are not visible in the textfield

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select reminder date and time"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Save"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
menu.tag =10;
[menu showInView:self.view];
UITextField  *txtReminderTitle= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 190, 280.0, 40.0)];
[txtReminderTitle setTag:99];
[txtReminderTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txtReminderTitle setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
[txtReminderTitle setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[txtReminderTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
txtReminderTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtReminderTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtReminderTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtReminderTitle.delegate =self;
[menu addSubview:txtReminderTitle];
```

Please pull me out of this problem..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Found That, When You add `UITextField` to `UIActionSheet` then `UITextField` is remain under `UIActionSheet` so you need to display `UITextField` above `UIActionSheet`

Write Following code for add `UITextField`:

```
UIWindow *appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[appWindow insertSubview:txtReminderTitle aboveSubview:menu];
```